# Tab equivalent for Mac while searching from website in chrome bar

Tags: google-chrome, search, google, mac, windows

For ex.
In Windows Chrome if you type youtube.com on bar and press tab it enables a textbox to search on youtube, What's the equivalent in Mac OS?

Answer (score 2):

Just keep typing, it will fill with suggestions, including direct search on YouTube itself, Siri suggestions, Google [or your preferred search engine] suggestions & Bookmarks/history.

Example…

[image]

Comment: Yeah, should clearly be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Use Keyword search extension for Safari

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/keyword-search/id1558453954

Comment: This app claims to do exacly what the question refers to @Thinkr.  Did you visit the link?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this functionality, *site search*, is disabled by default on Mac OS, or at least it was for me.

To enable it, go to

Chrome → Settings → Search Engine → Manage search engines and site search → Site Search

and enable the shortcuts you want from the list of available, inactive shortcuts. In case no shortcut is available for YouTube, you can manually add one. In my case, the default was:

- Search engine: YouTube Video Search
- Shortcut: youtube.com
- URL with %s in place of query: [https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s&page={startPage?}&utm_source=opensearch](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s&page=%7BstartPage?%7D&utm_source=opensearch)

It seems that only setting the `search_query` parameter in the URL is sufficient, the other parameters are probably used for analytics.